# Css menu problem

Tags: html, css

I'm currently working on this layout
http://imstillreallybored.com/gridiron/indexx.html

at the top menu i have to different backgrounds for the menu the red one and the gray gradient. I need the gray gradient to continue on the right side of the menu off of the page i cant seem to get this to work. I tried absolute positioning but when you resize the browser it covers the menu which wont work. I cant seem to think of the right way to do this anyone have any ideas?

Comment: So you need red on the left and gray on the right?

Comment: I have read this numerous times and am still unsure as to what end result you want. Can you maybe provide a picture of how you expect it to look, as the link you provided looks fine to me but am unsure as to your intentions.

Comment: yes exactly i cant get it to not cover the menu on resize to

Comment: i want the grey gradient to continue on the right but its a 960px centered layout

Answer (score 1):

You can create a very long background image for your `#menuContainer` that is half red and half grey, and then center position it, so it will always stay red on the left and grey on the right. It might be a hacky solution, but that is the easiest thing you can do without changing your markup.

Answer (score 1):

try nesting a few divs.  run the grey gradient all the way across, then put your red image over that in another div, and left align it.  make the red image like 500px wide and it'll always be on the left, but will extend under the menu and be hidden.

```
<div style="background-image:url('grey-gradient.jpg'); background-repeat:repeat-x;">
  <div style="background-image:url('red.jpg'); background-repeat:no-repeat;">
    <div>
      <ul>menu</ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```